# Integer solutions of nonhomogeneous linear inequalities

Tags: algorithms, inequality

I am trying to solve a problem which I have reduced down to find out one of integer solutions to a number of nonhomogeneous linear inequalities.

Can this be done efficiently ? If so: how?; if not: why?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing [integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). It's an NP-hard problem, so there are no known efficient (i.e., polynomial-time) solutions in general. However, this does not mean that your particular problem cannot be solved in reasonable time. Try the [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/).